# Best cost-effective manner to install Power Bi Gateway on AWS

Tags: powerbi

I work for a small startup where we operate on AWS, and I am the sole person responsible for data management where I present information using Power BI dashboards.

I chose to use the Import Mode to run scheduled refreshes because I've read that Direct Query tends to run slower on Power BI Service, and I want to ensure a smooth experience for the end-user.

Everything works well, but the challenge I'm facing is that I installed the Gateway on an AWS EC2 with an m5.2xlarge processor (I tried smaller processors before, but scheduled refreshes failed). However, this setup led to a cost of 500 USD for a month, which is unsustainable for us, especially given that it's only running the Gateway.

So my doubt is, How do you refresh Power BI dashboards in a more cost-effective manner?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could shut down the gateway when not in use.